# PHP code inside loadHTML()

Tags: php, html, load

I have the following PHP code

```
 $dom->loadHTML('
    <div id="logoutText">Logged in as: <? $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?> </div> 
 ');
```

But it literally prints:

```
<? $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?>
```

While, I want it to be the variable value. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Like this. 


    $dom->loadHTML('<div id="logoutText">Logged in as: '.$fgmembersite->UserEmail().' </div>');

Comment: Thanks it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$dom->loadHTML("<div id='logoutText'>Logged in as: $fgmembersite->UserEmail() </div>");
```

Or

```
$dom->loadHTML('<div id="logoutText">Logged in as: '.$fgmembersite->UserEmail().' </div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because it is seeing that as a string. You need to escape that variable like so:

```
$dom->loadHTML('<div id="logoutText">Logged in as: '". $fgmembersite->UserEmail() . "'</div>');
```